# Possible to import Excel formatted text?

Tags: import

Is it possible to import Excel text markup such as underlines? For example:

[image]

Yet

```
Import["/Users/alancalvitti/Dropbox/Understars/text.is.lyte/litany.of.\
duals/litany.of.duals.xlsx"][[1, 1]]
```

returns a list with the plain string:

```
{"nyt 7.23.12", "question for a ceo: what is yahoo?", "17 years after \
the company was founded, you still have to wonder whether the frothy \
trademark yahoo! should be replaced with yahoo? to convey the \
uncertainty of purpose", "david carr @nyt"}
```

Note that the formatting is partial, not a global formatting selection (such as font) that affects the whole cell.

Comment: I don't like this solution for a lot of reasons, but if you save your excel file as `xml` and read it with `Cases[Import["c:\\test3.xml", "xml"], 
 XMLElement["Cell", _, _], Infinity]`, the formatting is there

Comment: @belisarius, at the moment this is the only solution. If it's possible to programmatically convert xsl/xlsx --> xml in MMA itself (as a temporary variable) I'll accept that answer if you submit it as such.

Comment: As I said, I don't like it. Perhaps it is possible, but I am sure a lot of things will break in the process. If you absolutely need some emergency code, you have this. But it is just that, a dirty fix. (BTW, that is why I didn't post it as an answer)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Mathematica **can** import formatted text. But there is a small catch. Looks like *we can import format applied to an Excel cell as whole, but not formatting of a part of text inside the cell*. At least I did not find any options for this. Here is an example.

A lot of formatting was applied to part of text in the last cell, which you can see in Excel properties **when only that part is selected**:

[image]

If on other hand you click on the cell as whole, Excel properties show **original formatting as property of the whole cell**:

[image]

I guess, this is why, Mathematica did not import partial formatting - it picked up **formatting properties of the whole cell provided by Excel**:

```
Import["test.xlsx", "FormattedData"]
```

[image]

```
% // InputForm
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Vitaliy, for the explanation. Unfortunately It doens't help the situation at hand which is to recover partial formatting not for the whole cell (editing my original Q to reflect this). Is belisarius' xml "hack" the only solution then?